# Git repository using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git

I am trying to make a local repository using eclipse, I get this error,

```
Can not move project SE to target location /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/SE/SE, as this location overlaps with
```

location /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs, which contains a .project file

I was trying to make a repository for php project.
Any Help :)

Comment: Can't nest repositories.  If htdocs is already a Git repository, can't create a new one "under' it.

Comment: i can't even create repository in htdocs folder. any idea?

Comment: is htdocs or any of its parents a Git repository?

Comment: I created a git repo there before and deleted the project.

Comment: all remnants of it?  Did you delete the .git folder and the other project files?  do an "ls -a" to look for any "hidden" files

Comment: Yeah there are .  .DS_Store SE  xampp
..  .project webalizer
How can i remove .project??

Comment: rm command:  `rm .project`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked :D

Comment: no problem, you're welcome